# How to create SHA2 on Oracle DB

Tags: sha-2

How can I create a SHA2 certificate using Oracle Wallet if I have only Oracle 11.1 database?

I already tried and read a lot about SHA-2 under Oracle 11.1 db version but it´s not possible according to Oracle documentation.

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I create a SHA2 certificate using Oracle Wallet if I have only Oracle 11.1 database?

You can't. You have two options:

1. Upgrade Oracle to at least [version 12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS664), or
2. Use a public domain version of SHA256 (which is SHA2). See [SHA1, SHA256, SHA512 in Oracle for free without using DBMS_CRYPTO – Jakub Wartak's blog](http://jakub.wartak.pl/blog/?p=124)